# How do I sum up p items in a sequence?

Tags: list-manipulation, summation

I have the following sequence

list = {p1, p2, p3, p4 ....}

I am summing up the p items as follows:

p1 + p2 + 2*sqrt (p21*p2) = p12

p12 + p3 + 2*sqrt (p12*p3) = p123

p123 + p4 + 2*sqrt (p123*p4) = p1234

How do I get the end result to be an addition of p12 + p123 + p1234 ?

Comment: Have a look at `NestList`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Fold[#1 + #2 + 2*Sqrt[#1*#2] &, First[list], Rest[list]]
```

Comment: I have done this step for step with Symbols a, b, c, d., and I get another result. Also, I think you have to sum up the terms (p12 + p123 + p1234):

Comment: sorry mistake was on my part (typo)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I misread your intent, but I *think* what you're after is:

```
Total@Rest@FoldList[#1 + #2 + 2*Sqrt[1 ##] &, First[list], Rest[list]]
```